# vuex - data overwritten in dynamically registed modules

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a module let's call it `providers`. I dynamically register modules for individual providers using an `id`. Something like this:

```
[1, 2, 3].forEach((id) => {
  this.registerModule(['providers', id.toString()], ProviderModule);  
})
```

Each one of these `ProviderModule`'s has a module called `availabilities`. So the name space to this module looks like this: `` `providers/${id}/availabilities` ``

I make an api call to fetch data about each provider. The api call returns an array of objects(the availabilities) that map to each provider through id. For each object in the array, I dispatch an action in the corresponding module. Something like this:

```
response.data.forEach((providerAvailabilities) => {
  dispatch(`provider/${providerAvailabilities.id}/availabilities/load`, providerAvailabilities);
})
```

In the `load` action we commit the properties in a mutation and log some info:

```
[types.SET_AVAILABILITIES](state, payload) {
  console.log(payload);
  state.firstAvailable = payload.firstAvailable;
  state.id = payload.id;
  state.timeslots = payload.timeslots;
  console.log('state: ', state.timeslots);
}
```

The logs in the above code show exactly the data I want for each individual provider module as it loops through the response's data.

Here's the issue. For each time it loops through the response's data, it sets every provider's `availabilties`' properties, not just the provider the loop is currently in. As a result the `availabilities` that are rendered are always the last provider's `availabilities`.

To verify if that was the case, I put a log into a getter that grabs all my providers:

```
list: (state) => { 
  if (state.provider) {
    const providers = Object.keys(state.providers).map(key => state.providers[key]);
    console.log('current providers: ', providers.map(provider => provider.availabilities.timeslots));
    return providers;
  }
}
```

This would log out anytime provider's changed and each time the `load` action was fired, it would reset all the provider's `availabilities` to whichever iteration of the loop it was in.

That's about as far as I can chase the problem.

#### My questions:

1. What is causing the `load` action to set values for all `providers`?
2. How can I ensure that the right data gets set to the corresponding dynamically registered module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here and in the definition of ProviderModule:

```
[1, 2, 3].forEach((id) => {
  this.registerModule(['providers', id.toString()], ProviderModule);  
})
```

You are registering the same module ProviderModule with different names, but the underlying object is the same.

In short, in your module definition you should define your state the same way you define the data in component definitions, with a function returning an object instead of a static object:

```
state () {
    return {
      foo: 'bar'
    }
  },
```

The problem is documented here https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html (see Module Reuse section)

Comment: Yes, this was exactly the problem